# How to use parse to charge money from Customers account using Stirpe

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am developing for iOS app.And I have to implement some `in-App-Purchases`.
I Have generated the `token`.

Now I have to charge from clients `account`.

And I want to do it via [Parse](https://parse.com/).

Is there any way by which i can achieve this ??

Comment: call the create charge function provided by the stripe SDK and send the response to your server(by web service) once you get the response form the Stripe

Comment: how can i do it with Parse...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using in-app purchases, you would not use Stripe. Stripe would be used to allow purchases for a service, for example.

Comment: Well in general you would use Parse's Cloud Code, outlined [here](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#stripe) and then in your iOS Application when you initialize the purchase, you would call the function. You can check out stripes documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and then initialize the Parse Cloud Code you wrote earlier.